# I have not the mail option jmeter

Tags: email, jmeter

I want to read the mail from jmeter to get the code that arrives, 
but I do not have the option.

Please can you guide me to enable the option? Please can you help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mail Reader Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler) with defined configurations based on your email protocol to read the email.

Next add any of the [Post Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) as child to this sampler for reading the Code from response of mail sampler.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your JMeter installation got corrupt somewhere somehow, reinstalling [latest stable version](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) should fix the issue for you.

It might also be the case you're using [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) OS where [jmeter-mail](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/jmeter-mail) package needs to be installed separately.

In any case you can add/remove any JMeter component or [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) using J[Meter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image]